# Проверка корректности ввода через стандартный декоратор сеттер

Tags: python, декоратор, python-3.x

Есть какой-то класс в котором необходимо реализовать проверку введенных пользователем данных c использованием декораторов:

```
class SomeKlass(object):  
    __someProp = 0

    def __init__(self,param):
        self.someProp = param

    @property
    def someProp(self):
        return self.__someProp

    @someProp.setter
    def someProp(self, value):
        if value > 10:
            print("Some error")
            exit()
        else:
            self.__someProp = value
```

Метод **init** будет создан раньше сеттера т.е. сеттер не выполнится, а будет созданно новое свойство.
Этот пример необходим в образовательных целях  
Вопрос:  существует-ли способ реализовать проверку методом **init** без дублирования кода и через сеттер.

Comment: > Метод `__init__` будет создан раньше сеттера т.е. сеттер не выполнится, а будет созданно новое свойство.

Глупость. Декоратор вызывается при конструировании класса, а `__init__` вызывается только при инициализации объекта. Т.ч. в примере выше сеттер будт без проблем работать, в т.ч. и в `__init__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def getVal(self):
        print('get')

    def setVal(self, val):
        print("here is my value: {0}".format(val))

    value = property(getVal, setVal)

a = MyClass(14)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался.